# My Express Node.JS App times out

Tags: node.js, express

I have installed Node.js on my web server plus the dependencies for Express. When I run the command `npm start` and go to my web site's address using the port 3000 (which I believe the app is set to by default?), it just keeps loading and never loads. Any tipps please on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this `$ PORT=8080 node app.js`. Here `app.js` is your server config file. I suspect some background servers are running in that port 3000.